`std::fstream` can't overwrite content after read
I want to find a (fixed length) key in a file and update a value afterward. However, I found a strange behavior where I can't write to the file after reading from it. Here is an example:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    std::fstream file("test.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out);

    // Read the key
    const int key_size = 6;
    char key[key_size + 1] = {0};
    file.read(key, key_size);
    std::cout << "Key: " << key << std::endl;

    // std::streampos write_pos = file.tellp();
    // file.seekp(write_pos);

    file.write("123456", 6);
    return 0;
}

If test.txt contains hello world, the resulting file would contain hello world6. However, if I add a seekp after reading, the writing works as expected, producing the result hello 123456.
I want to understand why this behavior occurs and if there are any performance penalties associated with using the seekp fix.
Edit: The example works as expected with GCC but produces described  (unexpected) behavior with Clang and MSVC on Windows.

This is as expected. The file stream only has one position, which has to be  repositioned when switching from read to write, or vice versa.

Strange enough, the proposed example works as expected on my laptop (compiled with gcc12.3.1 on a Fedora 37)

@edrezen thanks for pointing that out. I updated the question with compiler information.

Check if the stream is still in a .good() state.

Yes, good method returns true before and after writing. @alfC

Got repro on MSVC: https://godbolt.org/z/fG8YfEK7j gcc and clang are fine. So maybe this is Windows "feature".
